# Motivate users who wish to follow a tag to create a Wiki for the tag if none exists?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-wiki

The concept of allowing users to write descriptions for tags presupposes that there exists people who are somewhat knowledgeable about the subject of the tag, and that some of them will be motivated enough to take the time to create and edit these descriptions.

It can, therefore, be said both about persons who follow tags and persons who edit tag wikis that

1. They care about the subject the tag represents
2. They know at least a little bit about the subject

If the same people who would follow a tag are the same people who would create and edit tag wikis, then *we should try to motivate users trying to follow a wikiless tag to create that tag wiki*.

I suppose there is the nice way to do this,

> We see you are following the [Derpify] tag.  This tag does not have a wiki.  Would you consider taking a minute or two to create one?  Please [click here to create a wiki for this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/0)

Or you could be an ass about it

> Sorry, you cannot follow a tag that does not have a wiki.  If you wish to follow this tag, please [click here to create a wiki for this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/0).  This will not only allow you to follow this tag, but will help drive more interest to questions with this tag.

Comment: _Great_ idea! Let's also use «Sorry, you cannot ask questions in a tag that has unanswered questions. If you wish to ask a question in this tag, please click here to answer…»

Comment: @GrigoryM: Your sarcasm.  It is not that good.

Comment: We have so many tags where I don't even *want* to think about a description, because they are so self-descriptive. Forcing users to create one isn't the right approach. A gentle reminder is okay, but  forcing them to create one is not.

Comment: @slhck: "We have so many tags where I don't even *want* to think about a description."  Let me guess--you don't follow a single one of them, right?  ***Kreskin!***

Comment: Fair point, but not entirely :) Can't talk about SO, but on SU for example, [`[sound]`](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sound) or [`[volume]`](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/volume) both have no description, but I'm following them. It wouldn't really make sense to write a description for them either (or at least, it's not *that* important).

Comment: Hmmm. It's an interesting suggestion, but I can't help but fear that  it would mainly lead to the creation of crappy tag wikis, or Wikipedia copy & pastes. Not everyone who is interested in a tag has the gift to write a wiki for it

Comment: @EatmoreTwisters: I find it hard to believe that someone who wants to follow a tag (which isn't something dbags and people who don't give a crap do) would write a crappy one.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think that writing tag wiki excerpts is a high art. It's *very* hard to be precise and to the point if you're supposed to write in a non-native language and you're restricted in the amount of characters you have.

Comment: @Won't hmmm. I see what you mean, but what if a user isn't well-versed enough in English to write a good Wiki? It *does* take some writing talent. I don't know. (edit - agree with @shlck)

Comment: WHY ARE YOU DOWNVOTING etc.  Anyhow, its a suggestion.  It came to me while investigating the [Toad] tag.  I was like, "What the hell is Toad?" then I was like "Dangit, no wiki" but then I was like "Wait, no tag wiki, but *seven people are following?*" and finally I was like "who the hell would follow a tag and yet leave it wikiless?"  Thought this would be a good way to help get wikis on tags, but ***noooooooooooo***.

Comment: I can see your motivation. I really do. I'm afraid though we'd have to do this differently. Quite a few people **don't care** about the tags, and they care about their wikis even less. After all, they're not necessary for the functionality of the site.

Comment: @slhck: Okay.  Some people don't care about tags or tag wikis.  Of course, this suggestion has nothing to do with these people.  I'm not exactly sure you are catching on to what I wrote, after that comment.

Comment: Right, my last comment wasn't about the group of users you mentioned (i.e. people who've already written tag wikis). As I said, I have nothing against your first proposal. It's surely a nice way to encourage creating wikis.

Comment: A +1 only for the non-ass version of this feature.

Answer (score 5):

**I think *suggesting to write a tag wiki* might be a good idea - but not requiring it.**

I'm following some tags where I'm not really knowledgeable enough to write answers (other than in trivial cases), but where I simply want to read interesting questions and the even more interesting answers to them.

It wouldn't be good for the tag wiki if I had to write something here just to name this tag one of my favorite ones.

(Actually, for all but one of my favorite tags there are already tag wikis, and I just wrote one for the [remaining one](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jzlib/info).)

Comment: This is the answer for all of you to upvote who only want the "suggest" half of Won't's proposal. :-)

Comment: [jzlib] doesn't have a tag wiki.

Comment: Yeah. *This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.*

Comment: @PaloEbermann: Damn, [the links were greyed out!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4iyuW.png)  I accepted your edits.