# Tag wikis and info should be more prominent, especially when asking questions

Tags: feature-request, tags, asking-questions, tag-wiki

I often find myself asking more questions about a topic that is new to me and many of the questions I have are already answered in other questions about that topic. Many of this existing knowledge base is already reachable through the tag(s) that relate to the topic.

It would be great, from a "learning a new technology area" standpoint if the tag information pages (tag wiki, tag FAQ, and tag votes) pages could be more visible from the Ask a Question screen.

Additional reasons why this would be useful:

1. Help people that may not have a broad knowledge of a technology area broaden themselves
2. It would also get more eyes on the tag wikis and possibly help them get better
3. Encourage users to look at older posts and upvote the ones that they found useful to their learning process
4. Serves to bring more useful content to the surface (it's a wonderful feeback loop)
5. Also has the effect of reducing the number of duplicate questions, since people are all learning the same sorts of things
6. It emphasizes that the HUGE body of content can almost become a curriculum, of sorts

I'm not really sure how to work this in, but one thought I had might be to surface tag info pages in a similar way to "Questions with Similar Titles". A side-bar location would be another place it could surface.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How might we *naturally* lead newbs to the tag wiki?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103456/how-might-we-naturally-lead-newbs-to-the-tag-wiki)

Comment: @ConradFrix - This idea is in the same vein, but is more targeted at users asking questions, not just searching. I'm also looking to help users who are not necessarily new to SO but don't think to look to the tag wiki's first either because they didn't know about them or forgot about them. This builds on the other question, in a way, because new users often seem to jump right in to asking a question, rather than searching, so this idea would help in that case as well.

Comment: did you see Marc's answer. Particularly the bit about the tag editor when asking questions

Comment: Yes, and while that is good, it's still a bit buried. By the time users are entering tags, they will have already spent the time and effort to put together a question (since it's at the bottom of the page), and are likely to just pick tags and submit rather than spend more time. It would be _much_ better to get them to the tag wiki info area _before_ they write the question, since it would save them work. Also, the links to "learn more" are rather easy to miss. Something a bit more up-front would be better IMHO. Something integrating @bmike's suggestion but less intrusive, perhaps.

Comment: wow that would be cool if the tag wikis could appear based on the title or question content.

Comment: @ConradFrix - Yes, that is sort of what I was thinking. Perhaps the top 1 or 2 most common tags across the already suggested similar questions. Most of the "hard" work is already done, since questions based on question title and content are already suggested. All you would need to do (other than adding it to the UI) would be to count the tags on those suggested questions and show the tag-wiki excerpt or something similar for the most common tags. More sophisticated searching could be done, but that would work for starters. SO should teach as much as possible, in my opinion.