# Why are "barely more than a link to an external site" answers deleted?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers

I just had an answer deleted by @Flexo that meets the criteria "barely more than a link to an external site".  Those with sufficient privileges can see it here: [different between CRC8 , CRC16 and CRC32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746541/different-between-crc8-crc16-and-crc32/13750657#13750657)

All of the questions posed are answered completely, and much more, in the tutorial that I linked to.  In my opinion, that is an excellent and complete answer, and it is very useful for others looking at those sorts of questions to be directed to that tutorial.  In fact the questioner said exactly that: "Thanks for the link. It is very useful. I didnt find any good links like this."

So basically, I disagree with the criteria: "barely more than a link to an external site" being applied without thought or inspection.  Such answers should be permitted when they are in fact answers and useful to others.  There is no value in repeating the tutorial or parts of the tutorial in the answer.

Other opinions?

Comment: What happens when the tutorial you linked to goes away and the question is completely useless for future visitors?

Comment: related: [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way)

Comment: That tutorial has been out there for 20 years, so I'm not real worried about it disappearing completely.  I could improve the answer with the title of the tutorial, with which a google search shows the dozen or so places it is available.  Except I can't improve the answer since it was deleted by a moderator.

Comment: The answer to the question, which was very broad, requires most of the tutorial.  So should I have simply copied the tutorial into the answer?  It's about 90K.

Comment: @MarkAdler: Which is why the question was just "put on hold as too broad" 2 minutes ago.

Comment: You should have just voted to close the question and posted the link in the comments as a reference. How can the question *not* be considered too broad when your answer is a link to a 37-page paper?

Comment: I can edit it, but I can't request undeletion.  It says it was deleted by a moderator and can't be undeleted.

Comment: @MarkAdler You can flag it, you can't undelete it yourself.  That said, I don't see it as a complete answer even after your edit.  The question, by your own admission, is too broad, and should just be closed.  Post your link as a comment if you would like.

Comment: I have added the link as a comment.

Comment: I see many questions on CRCs that are answered in this tutorial.  If people would just read it.  So if I put up a question something like: "Where can I find a really nifty tutorial on the theory and implementation of CRC algorithms?" and posted my own answer, would all that be deleted, held, disparaged as too broad and just a link?

Comment: @MarkAdler: it would be closed either as Too Broad, or as Off Topic: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: `That tutorial has been out there for 20 years, so I'm not real worried about it disappearing completely.` So every time someone posts a link-only answer, moderators should check out the link, figure out how long it's been out on the internet, and judge whether it is likely to remain working? There are many dead links in SO's old answers, so this is a very real problem.

Comment: Ok.  To recap, there is no permitted mechanism on SO to help direct people to something offsite, no matter how valuable or stable it may be, that answers the majority of the questions asked on a particular topic.

Comment: You are misinterpreting what people are saying. It is not alright to **just** direct people to something offsite. An answer should stand on its own. By all means - add a comment with the link. I know I do _that_ often enough.

Comment: That is what I meant.  I have in fact included that link on many answers to specific CRC questions, along with the answer in most cases.  But someone looking for answers on CRCs may or may not come across that link.

Comment: How about this: what if each tag could have associated with it a list of references relevant to that tag, where such a list would be maintained?  (There could be an automatic procedure to periodically check for link rot.)  Then someone putting in a tag would see the list pop up.

Comment: @MarkAdler, the feature intended for that kind of thing is [tag wikis](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169863/what-are-tag-wikis-for?rq=1), although they could use a bit of [love](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122197/tag-wikis-need-a-size-and-functionality-increase) and [visibility](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115482/tag-wikis-and-info-should-be-more-prominent-especially-when-asking-questions?rq=1).

Comment: Indeed, they're probably not getting a lot of love since they are almost invisible.  I had no idea they existed until now.  I guessed, turns out correctly, that the "about" link on the tag would get me there.  Perhaps SO could automatically bring up the wiki or perhaps the first part of the wiki if it's long, when a user adds that tag under the tag space for the question.  I am now adding links to the CRC tag wikis.  Though as it stands, it is likely that no one who needs to see them will see them.

Comment: By the way, it's great to see all the love you get here when you try to have a simple discussion about something.  There must be great satisfaction in piling on with everyone else the negative ones on the question.  I thought, apparently incorrectly, that this manner of topic was exactly what this meta forum was for.

Comment: @MarkAdler You're right, Meta is _exactly_ the correct place to come with a question such as yours. Unfortunately, a custom has arisen where people downvote questions here simply to indicate their _disagreement_ with your position. (Although, the fact that this issue has been discussed many times before also probably contributed here somewhat.)

Comment: @joran listen guys can you please understand that not all of us are expert programmers and maybe we could also... ask questions on a questions site?! Besides the fact that many of the motivations against this kind of answers could be discussed without flame wars or downvotes. But I'm not a programming expert or computer scientist so I don't know if I have the right to talk, luckily you cannot downvote a comment!

Answer (score 10):

Why?

Because they are not answering the question. They are pointing to something that *may* contain the answer, may contain it but is buried somewhere, may simply be spam. There is no way to know until someone *clicks* and parses it.

If someone has an answer they should give it there and then and a link to something that supports the answer is just a bonus.

Additionally - links rot. If a link works today and is relevant, great. But what about tomorrow, when that server/site dies or moves links around without redirecting?

Comment: I would just like to add: Regardless of how good the link is, if people were allowed link-only answers, then people can simply google and potentially answer any question without actually knowing a single thing about the topic. That's definitely not good for the quality of the site.

Comment: Another thing I am fond of adding regarding this: Stack Overflow is here to be a repository of questions and answers - not a collection of links.