# Could we mention the tag-wiki in the FAQ?

Tags: feature-request, new-users, tag-wiki, faq-update-request

There are a few questions here aiming at improving the visibility and use of the tag wiki. Some of the suggested answers have been taken up, such as auto-completion when adding tags to a question.

I've not seen anyone suggest popping a tag wiki section into the FAQ. Currently there is one vague reference to "tag wiki" there and it's unlikely to pique the interest of new users since it refers to a privilege requiring 5k rep.

I've come to see the tag wiki as a kind of topic-specific extension of the FAQ. If this is a good way of looking at it, maybe the main FAQ should do more than just barely acknowledge its existence.

Among other things it is worth explaining to new users that they ought to read the full wiki text of any tags they propose to add as it may help improve the quality of their question and subsequent answers. I would also make it clear that the tag wiki is maintained by the community and make a note of any privileges related to that.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103456/how-might-we-naturally-lead-newbs-to-the-tag-wiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FAQ is already longer than any new users actually read, as evidenced by the constant stream of questions that fall plainly into "what not to ask", so I'm a bit wary of making it even longer.

Currently tag wikis are best documented in [the privileges page about voting on them](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits):

> **What are tag wikis?**
>
> Tag wikis are a general introduction to a topic defined by that tag. They're a place to consolidate and form a sub-community around a tag. They contain, among other things, frequently asked questions in the tag, top users in the tag, and best recent answers in the tag.

(Note that this description is not the same as "topic-specific extension of the FAQ," but isn't at odds with that use either.)

Having the only documentation live there isn't necessarily new-user friendly, but the tag wikis aren't the only piece that falls into that category.